# How is the tsclient share created (in terms of Windows API)?

Tags: winapi, rdp, fuse, dokan, virtualfilesystem

Using the Windows RDP Client (`mstsc.exe`), I can share local resources with the host I'm connecting to.

For example if I share `C:\`, I can use it in the RDP session in `\\tsclient\c`.

What Windows API does the server side use to create the `\\tsclient` share?

(I'm not referring to the Virtual Channels within the RDP session, rather the Windows API calls for registering `\\tsclient` itself).

I'd like to create a virtual file system using the same approach, as an alternative to using a third party VFS driver such as `Dokan` or `WinFsp`.

Comment: I think the magic phrase you're looking for is "[network provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/network-provider-api)".

Comment: Nice!! THE Raymond Chen! Thanks very much! I've been reading your blog for a decade and really appreciate it. Thanks for all you do :)